MissingSchemaError : Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"
I was trying to connect to MongoDB database using mongoose and I also defined my model but while trying to run it I got the error given below
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"

here are a couple of things I tried
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const Schem = mongoose.Schema


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise


const md5 = require('md5')


const validator = require('validator')


const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-erros')


const passportalocalMongoose = require ('passport-local-mongoose')

const userSchema = new Schema ({
username: {
    type:string,
    unique: true
},
password:{
    type:string

},

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

})`


Typo.you defined const Schem = mongoose.Schema.change the const into Schema.

oh thanks for the correction but I'm still having same error

Which error you are currently getting?Please specify.

Yes there is another reason for which you are still getting error that I have also missed initially. Please have a look to my posted answer where I pointed out the error.Thanks

You are exporting userSchema within it's defination which is not a valid practice.At first You need to register or define the Schema and then you can export it.
That is the reason you are still getting error.
Change this code.
const userSchema = new Schema ({
username: {
    type:string,
    unique: true
},
password:{
    type:string

},

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

})`

And replace the above code with this.
const userSchema = new Schema ({
username: {
    type:string,
    unique: true
},
password:{
    type:string

},

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

